# add more information on the info box, Maps with SVG and jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

In the tutor "Dynamic Geo Maps with SVG and jQuery", I want to add more information on the info box by using `<br>`, but then the info box disappears. Please see the example below.

http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KDHfh

```
$(function() {

for(i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {

    $('#'+ regions[i].region_code)
    .css({'fill': 'rgba(11, 104, 170,' + regions[i].population/highest_value +')'})
    .data('region', regions[i]);
}

$('.map g').mouseover(function (e) {
    var region_data=$(this).data('region');
    $('<div class="info_panel">'+
        region_data.region_name + '<br>' +
        'Test: ' + region_data.test + '<br>' +
        'Population: ' + region_data.population.toLocaleString("en-UK") +
        '</div>'
     )
    .appendTo('body');
})
.mouseleave(function () {
    $('.info_panel').remove();
})
.mousemove(function(e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX, //X coordinates of mouse
        mouseY = e.pageY; //Y coordinates of mouse

    $('.info_panel').css({
        top: mouseY-50,
        left: mouseX - ($('.info_panel').width()/2)
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did minor modifications in js part

First of all added more data

```
    $('<div class="info_panel">' +
              region_data.region_name + '<br>' +
'Population: ' + region_data.population.toLocaleString("en-UK") +'<br>' +
'Population: ' + region_data.population.toLocaleString("en-UK") +'<br>' +
'Population: ' + region_data.population.toLocaleString("en-UK") +'<br>' +
'Population: ' + region_data.population.toLocaleString("en-UK") +'<br>' +
'Population: ' + region_data.population.toLocaleString("en-UK") +
              '</div>'
            )
```

And then modified this:

```
$('.info_panel').css({
        top: mouseY - $('.info_panel').height() - 20,
        left: mouseX - ($('.info_panel').width() / 2)
      });
```

And that seem to have solved the problem.

**Check the modified [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVOexr)**